# Python module problem

Tags: python, module, tkinter

I have two .py files called "notepad.py" & "pycolour.py". First is in the parent folder, second is in "subdir" folder.
First file:

```
#notepad.py
from Tkinter import *
from subdir import pycolour

class SimpleNotepad(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = Frame(root, bg='#707070', bd=1)
        self.text_field = Text(self.frame, font='Verdana 10', bd=3, wrap='word')
        self.text_field.focus_set()
        self.btn = Button(root, text='try to colour', command=self.try_to_colour)

        self.coloured = pycolour.PyColour(root)

        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.text_field.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.btn.pack()

    def try_to_colour(self):
        txt = self.text_field.get(1.0, 'end')
        text = str(txt).split('\n')
        for i in range(len(text)-1):
            self.coloured.colourize(i+1, len(text[i]))

root = Tk()
app = SimpleNotepad()
root.mainloop()
```

Second file:

```
#pycolour.py
from Tkinter import *
import keyword

#colorizing the Python code
class PyColour(Text):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Text.__init__(self, parent)
        self.focus_set()
        self.tag_conf()

        self.bind('<Key>', self.key_pressed)

    tags = {'com' : '#009999',   #comment is darkgreen
            'str' : '#F50000',   #string is red
            'kw'  : '#F57A00',   #keyword is orange
            'obj' : '#7A00F5',   #function or class name is purple
            'int' : '#3333FF'    #integers is darkblue
            }

    def tag_conf(self):
        for tag, value in self.tags.items():
            self.tag_configure(tag, foreground=value)

    def tag_delete(self, start, end):
        for tag in self.tags.items():
            self.tag_remove(tag, start, end)

    def key_pressed(self, key):
        if key.char in ' :[(]),"\'':
            self.edit_separator() #for undo/redo

        cline = self.index(INSERT).split('.')[0]
        lastcol = 0
        char = self.get('%s.%d'%(cline, lastcol))
        while char != '\n':
            lastcol += 1
            char = self.get('%s.%d'%(cline, lastcol))

        self.colourize(cline,lastcol)

    def colourize(self, cline, lastcol):
        buffer = self.get('%s.%d'%(cline,0),'%s.%d'%(cline,lastcol))
        tokenized = buffer.split(' ')

        self.tag_remove('%s.%d'%(cline, 0), '%s.%d'%(cline, lastcol))

        quotes = 0
        start = 0
        for i in range(len(buffer)):
            if buffer[i] in ['"',"'"]:
                if quotes:
                   self.tag_add('str', '%s.%d'%(cline, start), '%s.%d'%(cline, i+1))
                   quotes = 0
                else:
                    start = i
                    quotes = 1
            elif buffer[i] == '#':
                self.tag_add('com', '%s.%d'%(cline, i), '%s.%d'%(cline, len(buffer)))
                break

        start, end = 0, 0
        obj_flag = 0
        for token in tokenized:
            end = start + len(token)+1
            if obj_flag:
                self.tag_add('obj', '%s.%d'%(cline, start), '%s.%d'%(cline, end))
                obj_flag = 0
            if token.strip() in keyword.kwlist:
                self.tag_add('kw', '%s.%d'%(cline, start), '%s.%d'%(cline, end))
                if token.strip() in ['def','class']: obj_flag = 1
            else:
                for index in range(len(token)):
                    try: int(token[index])
                    except ValueError: pass
                    else: self.tag_add('int', '%s.%d'%(cline, start+index))
            start += len(token)+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    st = PyColour(root)
    st.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
    root.mainloop()
```

"pycolour.py" colours the python syntax in it's own text widget. I want to colour python syntax in text widget called "text_field" from "notepad.py", so i wrote `try_to_colour` function. the problem is that i do not understand why this function doesn't work properly.

Comment: You're going to get an error on the very first line, `from subdir import pycolour`, because that's not a command for importing a module from a subdirectory, so why not ask why *that's* giving you an error?

Comment: you should be a little more specific. Are you running the scripts from the command line? what output do you get? any exceptions?

Comment: @kinall, there is no mistake in this statement, subdir has "__init.py" inside.

Comment: @F.C., this is a gui based program, so it's enough just to doubleckicking on it

Comment: Ah, that'll work then. But then it's not a subdirectory, but a module.

Comment: @Saul_Tigh, when you are debugging is always useful to run the code from a terminal so you can see any output that the program sends to stdout

Answer (score 1):

PyColour is a class. In order to take advantage of what it does you must either create an instance of it (eg `self.text_field = PyColour(...)`) or create your own class that subclasses the PyColour class (eg `class MyPyColour(PyColour): ...; self.text_field = MyPyColour(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

`PyColour` is not a utility class but a `Text` widget. It can only color itself. So what you need to do is replace

```
self.text_field = Text(self.frame, ....)
```

with

```
self.text_field = PyColor(self.frame)
# find a different way to set font, etc.
```

The problem is that `PyColor` calls `self.tag_add()` and similar methods in `colourize()`. These work only on the `PyColor` instance `self`, not on your widget.

Comment: i think, i something misunderstood, because this trick don't work.

Comment: okay, "pycolour.py" colours the Python syntax in it's own text widget. no problem with that, but i want to use it in my code, so it colour Python syntax in text widget from "notepad.py". no error have been given, that's why i'm so confused.

Comment: What is "my code"? Is that a widget or what? In your question, you said you **don't** want to color the text. So my answer explains how to **disable** the code in `pycolor.py`. I understand that English is not your native language but please make sure that your question actually says what you want to know...

Comment: i edited my question. i think, it's easy to understand my problem. thanks in advance.